# How can I make the display and the value different for a html form datalist option?

Tags: html, forms, html-datalist

How can I make the display and the value different for an html form datalist option?

For instance, for a select-option field, I can write:  `<option value="Fake">Sample</option>` where "Sample" is displayed, but "Fake" is the value posted.

For a datalist, `<option value="Sample" />`, "Sample" is both displayed and used as the posted value.

How can I make it so I can post a different value from Sample in a datalist?  Thanks!

I need this so I can dynamically populate the datalist from MySQL, displaying a name while using an ID, for example `<option value="2">Bob</option>` (if this were a select-option field instead of a database field).

---

I discovered that I could use `<option value="Fake" label="Sample"/>`, which will hide it in Firefox, but Opera still displays both the Value and the Label. Anyone have any further ideas to display Sample, but hide Fake?

Comment: what is datalist? is this :- http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/datalist

Comment: Yes, that's the datalist to which I'm referring.

Comment: can you post your example on jsfiddle (html only)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Seems you can't with pure HTML without using some JS+CSS help.